# Button is not fired normally and fired when UseSubmitBehavior="false" but textbox values are coming null

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using ASP button its working properly at client side but on server side its not firing.

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <div>
        <div id="UserName">
            <b>LoginName</b>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_LoginName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
         <div id="Password">
             <b>Password&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Password" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: right; width: 210px;">
        <asp:Button ID="btn_SignIn" OnClientClick="LogInUser()" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" Text="Login`enter code here`" />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_InValidError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Client Side Code:

```
    function LogInUser()
    {
        var LoginName = document.getElementById("<%=txt_LoginName.ClientId %>").value;
        var Password = document.getElementById("<%=txt_Password.ClientId%>").value;

        if(LoginName == '')
        {
            alert("Please Enter UserName.");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(Password == '')
            {
                alert("Please Enter Password.");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                alert("You are logged in");                   
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Server Side Code

```
Protected Sub btn_SignIn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_SignIn.Click
 If Trim(Me.txt_LoginName.Text) = "" Then
            lbl_InValidError.Text = "Please Enter Login Name."
            Return
        End If
        If txt_Password.Text = "" Then
            lbl_InValidError.Text = "Please Enter Password."
            Return
        End If
End Sub
```

when I am not using `UseSubmitBehavior=false` event is not fire at server side.

Comment: I have tested your code and it works as expected for me...

Answer (score 0):

Change your OnClientClick to:

```
OnClientClick="if (LogInUser() == false) return;"
```

This way, if the user is not validated, it blocks the postback, but if valid, it allows it to continue.